# How to run casperjs code with button in php

Tags: php, html, node.js, casperjs

I have some casperjs code. When I click button in php. It will run the casperjs code. How can I do it. This is my casperjs code.

```
    var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
    userAgent: 'BotLenMqBrowser Mozilla/31.00'
    }
    });

    const url = 'url'

    casper.start(url);

    casper.then(function(page) {
       this.wait(100, function() {
        this.evaluate(function() {
        // giriş ekranı
        var email = 'mail'; // email
        var password = 'password'; // parola

        document.getElementById('login').value = email;
        document.getElementById('password').value = password;
        document.getElementsByClassName('loginButton')[0].click()
    });


    this.echo('loginyapildi0');
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what do you mean by "when I click button in PHP" ?

Comment: There will be button in website and when I click this button it will run the casperjs code. I didn't try anything